# SQL Server 2005 - are stored procedures named sp_MSdel_ related to replication?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-replication

I have a server here in my home office setup to receive push subscriptions from a server at our company HQ.  I was looking through the list of stored procedures today and see many of them with 'sp_MSdel_' prepended.  Are these related to replication?  Can they/should they be deleted or left alone?

I don't see any of these types of stored procs on the main server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tables are for replication. Dont delete these procedures as the SQL Agent will have replication clean up jobs that will use these procedures and is internal to the MS replication configuration setting. Please leave them be.

Answer (score 1):

They are for replication.  Leave them.